# Union rows to columns in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

This is the table "tbltask",

```
task    Ship_Operator   Pick_Operator   Pack_Operator
1       john            kevin           steve
2       kevin           kevin           john
3       steve           john            john
4       steve           steve           steve
5       john            steve           john
```

Now I need to get the total amount for everyone: ship, pick, pack

```
name    ship Total  pick Total  pack Total
john    2           1           3
kevin   1           2           0
steve   2           2           2
```

I can use three statement to get the result:

```
select [Ship_Operator] ,count(*) as task_total  from tbltask 
where [Ship_Operator] in ('john','kevin','steve')
group by [Ship_Operator]

select [Pick_Operator] ,count(*) as task_total from tbltask 
where [Pick_Operator] in ('john','kevin','steve')
group by [Pick_Operator]

select [Pack_Operator] ,count(*) as task_total from tbltask 
where [Pack_Operator] in ('john','kevin','steve')
group by [Pack_Operator]
```

Is it possible to use one SQL statement?
Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: well, err, use union?

Comment: Your expected output in incorrect. John is 3 times in pack.

Comment: GurV , thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unpivot` and `pivot` back:

```
with t(task,Ship_Operator,Pick_Operator,Pack_Operator) as (
select '1','john','kevin','steve'  union all
select '2','kevin','kevin','john'  union all
select '3','steve','john','john'   union all
select '4','steve','steve','steve' union all
select '5','john','steve','john')
-------Test data set up ends here------------

select 
    name, Ship_Operator ship_total, Pick_Operator pick_total, Pack_Operator pack_total
from t unpivot (
    name for operation in (Ship_Operator, Pick_operator, Pack_Operator)
) as x pivot (
    count(task) for operation in ([Ship_Operator],[Pick_Operator],[Pack_Operator])
) as x;
```

Produces:

[image]

Another way is to use `UNPIVOT` only and then conditionally aggregate:

```
with t(task,Ship_Operator,Pick_Operator,Pack_Operator) as (
select '1','john','kevin','steve'  union all
select '2','kevin','kevin','john'  union all
select '3','steve','john','john'   union all
select '4','steve','steve','steve' union all
select '5','john','steve','john')
-------Test data set up ends here------------

select 
    name,
    count(case when operation = 'Ship_Operator' then 1 end) ship,
    count(case when operation = 'Pick_Operator' then 1 end) pick,
    count(case when operation = 'Pack_Operator' then 1 end) pack
from t unpivot (
    name for operation in (Ship_Operator, Pick_operator, Pack_Operator)
) as x
group by name;
```

Produces:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION` to combine all name and add a new column to just identify the different values.

**Query**

```
SELECT t.[Name],
SUM(CASE t.[Col1] WHEN 'Ship' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Ship Total],
SUM(CASE t.[Col1] WHEN 'Pick' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Pick Total],
SUM(CASE t.[Col1] WHEN 'Pack' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Pack Total]
FROM(
    SELECT 'Ship' AS [col1], [Ship_operator] as [Name]
    FROM [tbltask]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Pick', [Pick_operator]
    FROM [tbltask]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Pack' AS [col1], [Pack_operator]
    FROM [tbltask]
)t
GROUP BY t.[Name];
```

And if you want the result particularly for those three names. Then add a `WHERE` condition in the sub-queries.